# Is it possible to generate bitcoins with a Google Chrome extension?

Tags: cpu-mining, gpu-mining

I just came across [Rlweb's Bitcoin Generator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/piobcnfhopbhgpkglmfclghgjahjhalf), a Chrome extension that claims to be the "first google chrome extension creating Bitcoins".

This extension looks quite shady to me, they don't even have a link to their website. Is it a scam?

Would it at least in theory be possible to write a miner application as a browser extension?
With GPU support?

**Edit**: For completeness, I found another Chrome extension named [Bitcoin Miner](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dcmbmmhjekejnneeomopbdnfkapnicgk).
This one looks more legit, but it says it's a Flash game. It doesn't really generate bitcoins, or does it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bitcoin Miner extension is simply this [flash game](http://chrazyapps.com/?p=347). Rlweb's Bitcoin Generator does not seem to do anything at the moment.  As far as I understand from the description, this should be a client for the [bitp.it](http://www.bitp.it) pool, but it just adds a button to chrome that shows some text.

Mining with your browser is possible. There is an open source [javascript CPU miner](https://github.com/jwhitehorn/jsMiner), but it is [no longer being developed](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=9042.0) because the difficulty is too high to mine with Javascript. Like Evil Spork said, other alternatives supporting WebCL and other browser plugins are coming up, but I don't know of any for Google Chrome.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I cannot speak for that specific generator. However there has been a javascript generator already in use and Chrome extentions are I believe javascript based, so it is very possible.

The javascript generator only uses CPU mind you, and is quite slow.

As for using the GPU, that is a possibility with some of the browser plugins out there, such as Unity. However a native browser? not very likely, they try very hard to restrict hardware access.

Comment: There have been javascript miners that use GPU, at least on Firefox.

Comment: Show me? I'm rather curious how they managed it.

Comment: KradMiner was once alive, now I'm getting 502 errors. https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=9876.0

Comment: ah, it uses a firefox plugin WebCL, so.. as I said.